# Order of appearance of previously defined values in a matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have many separate matrices in Matlab like this one

```
0   
6   
6   
7   
8   
8   
0   
2   
6   
6   
8   
7   
8   
8   
7   
1   
2   
2   
0   
1
```

I'm trying to create a Matlab script to generate a second column where I report the order of appearence (i.e. a value of 1 for the 1st, of 2 for the 2nd and 3 for the 3rd) of 3 particular values - in this case 0, 1 and 2 - while adding simply a 0 for all the other values.
This would be the result:

```
0   1
6   0
6   0
7   0
8   0
8   0
0   1
2   2
6   0
6   0
8   0
7   0
8   0
8   0
7   0
1   3
2   2
2   2
0   1
1   3
```

As can be seen above, among my 3 specific values (i.e. 0, 1 and 2) 0 is the first that appeared (hence a 1 is added to the second column), 2 is the 2nd (i.e. a 2 goes in second column) and 1 is the 3rd (3 in second column). All the other values (6,7,8... and there can be more) have a 0 reported in the second column.

Also, those specific values could change in future (i.e. in some cases I would like to be able to define for instance 4,5 and 6 as specific values whose order should be computed in the second column instead of 0,1,2).

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution looping over the sought values (since there are few of those values, using a loop shouldn't be slow):

```
%// Data
vector = [0 6 6 7 8 8 0 2 6 6 8 7 8 8 7 1 2 2 0 1].';
values = [0 1 2];

%'// Computations   
for ii = 1:numel(values)
  first(ii) = find(vector==values(ii),1);
end
[~, use_values] = sort(first);
[~, use_values] = sort(use_values);
result = zeros(numel(vector),2);
result(:,1) = vector;
for ii = 1:numel(values)
  result(vector==values(ii),2) = use_values(ii);
end
```

Comment: Thank you vert much! Your example works perfectly and now I'm trying to generalize to my real matrix, which is composed of 8 columns.
I should pick the original values from column 7 just when column 8 contains the value 2, then I create column 9 that should encode the order of the values specified in the vector. It seems to work but the result is not correct (the order encoded is not correct), any hint with the real-world case?

Comment: Here's the code:
`myMatrix(:,9) = 0; %CREATE COLUMN 9 WITH VALUE 0

values = [3 4 5];
for ii = 1:numel(values)
  first(ii) = find(myMatrix(:,7)==values(ii),1);
end
[~, use_values] = sort(first);
for ii = 1:numel(values)
myMatrix(myMatrix(:,7)==values(ii),9) = use_values(ii);
end`

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I don't want to use the entire column 7, but use the value in column 7 if the value at the same index in column 8 is equal to 4. In short, I can create the vector matrix like this `vector = myMatrix(find(myMatrix(:,7) & myMatrix(:,8)==4),7);
`

Comment: `myMatrix(:,9) = 0;
values = [3 4 5];
for ii = 1:numel(values)
    first(ii) = find(myMatrix(myMatrix(:,8)==4,7)==values(ii),1);
end
[~, use_values] = sort(first);
for ii = 1:numel(values)
    myMatrix(myMatrix(:,8)==4 & myMatrix(:,7)==values(ii), 9) = use_values(ii);
end`

Comment: thank you. it seems to work but the results are wrong. If I use `values = [3 4 5]` I obtain `use_values = [3 1 2]` meaning that 5 appears as second. However if I type `find(myMatrix(:,7)==4 & myMatrix(:,8)==4,1)` ans is 173002, while with `find(myMatrix(:,7)==5 & myMatrix(:,8)==4,1)` ans = 103999. Meaning that 5 is at the first place, while the script computes 5 at the 2nd place (`values = [3 4 5]` -> `use_values = [3 2 1]`). This is what I can't figure out...

Comment: What does `[~, use_values] = sort(first);` do exactly? This is the only line I don't understand. If I comment it and run the script on my real matrix I get the same results.

Comment: @Albz It sorts but returns the indices of the sorting instead of the sorted values

Comment: what I can't figure out is why I have `values = [3 4 5]`, `first = [120500 173002 103999]` and `use_values = [3 1 2]`... use_values should be = [2 3 1] if you check the lines number in first.

Comment: @Albz. You're right. My bad. Second output of `sort` gives the necessary reordering, not the current rank. So you need an extra step. See updated answer: new `sort` line after the old one. Now it should work

Comment: @Albz Actually you've helped too with the answer :-) I'm upvoting your question for that

Comment: Thank you. FYI after working with your script a bit and adapting it, I have a follow up that I posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20600649/order-of-appearance-non-contiguous-predefined-values-in-a-matlab-matrix) in case you want to contribute there too :)

Comment: @Albz Just saw that :-)