# Order of appearance non-contiguous predefined values in a Matlab matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a 9-columns matrix like this one:

```
X   X   X   X   X   X   0   2   0
X   X   X   X   X   X   6   2   0
X   X   X   X   X   X   6   2   0
X   X   X   X   X   X   7   2   0
X   X   X   X   X   X   8   2   0
X   X   X   X   X   X   8   2   0
X   X   X   X   X   X   0   2   0
X   X   X   X   X   X   0   2   0
X   X   X   X   X   X   0   2   0
X   X   X   X   X   X   6   2   0
X   X   X   X   X   X   8   2   0
X   X   X   X   X   X   7   2   0
X   X   X   X   X   X   8   2   0
X   X   X   X   X   X   8   2   0
X   X   X   X   X   X   1   2   0
X   X   X   X   X   X   1   2   0
X   X   X   X   X   X   2   2   0
X   X   X   X   X   X   2   2   0
X   X   X   X   X   X   0   2   0
X   X   X   X   X   X   1   2   0
X   X   X   X   X   X   2   2   0
X   X   X   X   X   X   2   2   0
X   X   X   X   X   X   2   2   0
X   X   X   X   X   X   2   2   0
X   X   X   X   X   X   2   2   0
X   X   X   X   X   X   2   2   0
X   X   X   X   X   X   2   2   0
X   X   X   X   X   X   8   2   0
X   X   X   X   X   X   0   2   0
X   X   X   X   X   X   1   2   0
```

I use X as a value for the columns that in this example are not relevant.
Column 9 originally contains just zeroes. 
What I want to achieve is changing values in column 9, corresponding to the order of appearence of pre-defined values (while all the other values remain 0).

In the script I should be able to specify a number of values (in the resulting matrix below: 0, 1 and 2) that should be counted progressively every time they appear (non-continuosly) in the column. This should be the result:

```
X   X   X   X   X   X   0   2   1
X   X   X   X   X   X   6   2   0
X   X   X   X   X   X   6   2   0
X   X   X   X   X   X   7   2   0
X   X   X   X   X   X   8   2   0
X   X   X   X   X   X   8   2   0
X   X   X   X   X   X   0   2   2
X   X   X   X   X   X   0   2   2
X   X   X   X   X   X   0   2   2
X   X   X   X   X   X   6   2   0
X   X   X   X   X   X   8   2   0
X   X   X   X   X   X   7   2   0
X   X   X   X   X   X   8   2   0
X   X   X   X   X   X   8   2   0
X   X   X   X   X   X   1   2   3
X   X   X   X   X   X   1   2   3
X   X   X   X   X   X   2   2   4
X   X   X   X   X   X   2   2   4
X   X   X   X   X   X   0   2   5
X   X   X   X   X   X   1   2   6
X   X   X   X   X   X   2   2   7
X   X   X   X   X   X   2   2   7
X   X   X   X   X   X   2   2   7
X   X   X   X   X   X   2   2   7
X   X   X   X   X   X   2   2   7
X   X   X   X   X   X   2   2   7
X   X   X   X   X   X   2   2   7
X   X   X   X   X   X   8   2   0
X   X   X   X   X   X   0   2   8
X   X   X   X   X   X   1   2   9
```

The values in column 7 that should be counted are, in this example, values = [0 1 2] (the order is not important: [1 2 0] should give the same results).

In the example final matrix the value of 0 (one of the values specified in "values") appears in the first line, so it becomes 1 (i.e. "First time that one of the values in "values" appears in column 7") in column 9, then other values follow and column 9 doesn't change (still 0). Then a 0 appears, so rank 2 (2nd appearence of one values specified in "values") is added in column 9. The 0 appears three times in continuos lines, in case of contiguous appearence, the value of column 9 is maintains the same rank (e.g. 2). And so on as in the example.

I already have the following code that I changed based on [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20597615/order-of-appearance-of-previously-defined-values-in-a-matrix-in-matlab/):

```
ALLphases(:,9) = 0; %CREATE COLUMN 9 WITH VALUE 0 everywhere

session = 2; 
values = [0 1 2]; 

for ii = 1:numel(values)
    first(ii) = find(ALLphases(ALLphases(:,8)==session,7)==values(ii),1);
end
[~, use_values] = sort(first);
[~, use_values] = sort(use_values);
for ii = 1:numel(values)
    ALLphases(ALLphases(:,8)==session & ALLphases(:,7)==values(ii), 9) = use_values(ii);
end
```

This is almost there, but I need it to count progressively all the values, even though they appeared previously.

Notice that the changes of values in column 9, based on column 7 occurr just if column 8 is equal to 2 (called "session" in the code above). This is a requirement related to the organization of my particular matrix.

How can I achieve my final goal?

Comment: +1 for well-formulated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you want, without loops: just some indexing and `diff`. (Not sure if I'm dealing with row 8 correctly, though):

```
matrix = [zeros(6,10); 0 3 4 1 1 0 2 6 1 2; 2*ones(1,10)].'; %'// example data
values = [0 1 2]; %// example data

ind = ismember(matrix(:,7), values) & matrix(:,8)==2; %// detect values
ind2 = ind & logical(diff([inf; matrix(:,7)])) ; %// detect start of runs   
[ind3, ~, fill] = find(cumsum(ind2).*ind); %// fill at ind, increasing as per ind2
matrix(ind3,9) = fill;
```

Example result:

```
>> matrix

matrix =

     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     2     1
     0     0     0     0     0     0     3     2     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     4     2     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     2     2
     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     2     2
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     2     3
     0     0     0     0     0     0     2     2     4
     0     0     0     0     0     0     6     2     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     2     5
     0     0     0     0     0     0     2     2     6
```

Comment: What seems to be missing is that, if a value in `values` is contiguous to a previous equal value, it maintains the same rank in column 9 (and it doesn't become 0). For what I need, your 9th column would be [1 0 0 2 **2** 3 4 0 5 6]

Comment: Great! The very last thing is that if you run the script twice on the same matrix with different values for column 8, it overwrites with zeroes the previous results. I'm gonna need to run the same script on the same matrix for different values of column eight... Is there a way to prevent to replace previous values of column 9 if they are not to be changes (i.e. if they are not on the same line of the `values`)?

Comment: @Albz See updated answer. Now it doesn't write any zeros in column 9, only nonzero values

Comment: It works perfectly... how would I do now if I wanted to use your script,but after having used it, also change the values 7 or 8 and 6 around these defined `values` (e.g. detect a pattern) (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20607014/change-values-in-a-matrix-according-to-a-predefined-pattern-in-matlab/)?