# Match patterns in a matrix with a variable number of lines and count them in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, pattern-matching

I have a matrix like this one:

```
8   
8   
8   
2   
2   
2   
6   
6   
7   
7   
7   
1   
1   
6   
6   
6   
6   
8   
8   
0   
6   
8   
8   
1   
6   
6
```

There are fixed patterns that always repeat. I would like to detect them. They repeat according to these rules:

Lines with 7 followed by lines with a number which can be (0, 1 or 2), followed by a 6

Lines with 8 followed by lines with a number which can be (0, 1 or 2), followed by a 6

For each one of the values on a single pattern detected (independently from the number of lines they are composed of), write in a second column a number of rank, starting from 1 and incrementing each time a new pattern in column one is detected. This would be the result:

```
    8   1
    8   1
    8   1
    2   1
    2   1
    2   1
    6   1
    6   1
    7   2
    7   2
    7   2
    1   2
    1   2
    6   2
    6   2
    6   2
    6   2
    8   3
    8   3
    0   3
    6   3
    8   4
    8   4
    1   4
    6   4
    6   4
```

Column 2 encodes in each line the first pattern (series of values = 1 meaning that on this line there is data related to patter 1), the second pattern (values 2) and so on...
How can I do that?

Comment: It is not really clear how you want to fill the matrix. Could you perhaps show a smaller example, but one with complete information? Also the first 6 columns don't seem to matter so you can probably leave those out of the example.

Comment: I simplified the question. I hope it's clearer now...

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that only uses the "closing tags" to split the matrix into parts:

```
function b = replaceValues(a)
  closingTag = 6;
  % Find all closing tag positions
  clTagPos = a(:, 1) == closingTag;
  % Keep only the "last" tags and add matrix start/end positions
  splitPoints = [0; find(diff(clTagPos) == -1); length(a)];
  % Split matrix into cell array
  acell = mat2cell(a, diff(splitPoints));
  % Replace the second column of each part with the corresponding non-zero value
  bcell = cellfun(@(c)[c(:, 1) ones(length(c), 1)*c(find(c(:, 2), 1), 2)], acell, 'UniformOutput', 0);
  % Convert back to matrix
  b = cell2mat(bcell);
end
```

Example input-output in Matlab:

```
a =  

 8     0
 8     0
 8     0
 2     1
 2     1
 2     1
 6     0
 6     0
 7     0
 7     0
 7     0
 1     2
 1     2
 6     0
 6     0
 6     0
 6     0
 8     0
 8     0
 0     3
 6     0
 8     0
 8     0
 1     4
 6     0
 6     0

>> b = replaceValues(a)

b =

 8     1
 8     1
 8     1
 2     1
 2     1
 2     1
 6     1
 6     1
 7     2
 7     2
 7     2
 1     2
 1     2
 6     2
 6     2
 6     2
 6     2
 8     3
 8     3
 0     3
 6     3
 8     4
 8     4
 1     4
 6     4
 6     4
```

Comment: Thanks, it doesn't work though. I get this error: Attempted to access c(:,2); index out of bounds because size(c)=[209000,1].

Comment: It works on the example you posted above, right? Is there some major difference between this and the data set that result in the error?

Comment: the original matrix is composed of 9 columns and column 1 in the example corresponds to column 7, while column 2 in the example corresponds to column 9, but I'm not sure this is the problem

Comment: Actually I also run into errors. Could you add some example input as I suspect that it may be expected in a different format than I tried.

Comment: What are the errors? The above function has the exact input-output behavior the OP originally requested (see the example I added).